# Can I cross from the eastern side of Kosovo to Serbia by bike?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, bicycles, serbia, kosovo

Similar questions have been asked, but they were from 7 years ago, so I want to see if there has been any diplomatic updates. My goal is to bike from Pristina, Kosovo to Sofia, Bulgaria. Google maps recommends going all the way south to North Macedonia. I have a time limit, so if that is the case I will have to plan a different route altogether. (This is just for vacation, so if the crossing would involve anything to risky, I'll just plan a different route.)

On Google maps I placed `Park per fushen e futbollit, Rruga Madenit, Karaçevë e Epërme` and `Restaurant Oxygen, Te Lisi Karaçevë e Epërme XK, 62000` as the start and end. It appears that both are in Kosovo (although maybe the destination is a Serbian enclave). Google still recommends travelling through North Macedonia.
[image: route]

Before I give up on this plan, I am wondering if Google is misleading me. What makes me suspicious is that I see that R124 in Kosovo connects the two places (The only article I found about that route was from a Dutch wiki https://www.wegenwiki.nl/Rruga_regjionale ). So supposedly *some* people cross that border. I am an American citizen, can I cross the border?

Comment: I did a bit of searching and found news articles from December 2022 reporting closure of border crossings.  I have no idea about the current state of affairs, but I wouldn't be surprised if Google maps is reflecting it relatively accurately.

Comment: On the contrary, I'd say the Google Maps route is illogical. The shortest route between those two points does not cross any border, so why take a detour through multiple border checkpoints? Is the road really impassable for bicycles? Unlikely.

Comment: Google Maps bike routing can be very strange indeed.  I've seen some crazy detours.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK but in this case its pedestrian routing as there are no bicycling directions available in the area.

Comment: @Johnnyjanko indeed, I had assumed that there must be a border blockade to the west of the actual border (and of the restaurant), but the restaurant's online presence makes it seem unlikely that it's accessible only from the eastern side of the border. Apple maps shows that you can drive from Muhovac to Karaçevë e Epërme on the R-214, but ViaMichelin (which I started using when they had detailed coverage in Sarajevo long before Google did) shows that you have to go through Bujanovac, making it a 49 km trip.  Still better than the 127 km from Google.

Comment: @phoog they're only marginally better - I tested Google walking recently

Comment: Future readers: note that this situation may well change as the [Ohrid agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_on_the_path_to_normalisation_between_Kosovo_and_Serbia) is implemented.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Unfortuately, the agreement has not yet been agreed in written. Therefore its implementation is a speculation. In fact, its ratification is at risk, given that the mediators like Josep Borell are rigid and undiplomatic, see your linked article "Borrell warned the leaders of Serbia and Kosovo that "Any attempt to question the agreement is futile. This agreement was agreed. It has to be implemented. And there is no room for picking and choosing. We will closely monitor who implements it and who does not." vs the Serbian leadership position ...

Comment: I'll just tell you that I think you are crazy for planing to do that. And I hope you got bodyguards following you.

Answer (score 16):

Please note: when you are in Kosovo, you already entered Serbia, from the serbian legal perspective.

If you directly enter Kosovo from *outside* Serbia, from the Serbian perspective you never officially and legally entered Serbia. Therefore, if you manage or try to enter Serbia from Kosovo, it means (from the serbian perspective) you already entered illegally in Serbia. So they will not allow you to stay in Serbia (from their point of view Kosovo is Serbia). Even less to further travel through Serbia.

See the informations provided by the serbian consulate in Lebanon:
http://www.beirut.mfa.gov.rs/consularservicestext.php?subaction=showfull&id=1581599779&ucat=17&template=MeniENG&

Answer (score 6):

Unless your last entry to Kosovo was from Serbia (Serbia-Kosovo-Serbia), you'll be refused entry to Serbia from Kosovo on a foreign passport as the Serbs don't issue entry stamps at those checkpoints, with a Kosovan entry stamp NOT deemed a valid substitute. An ID card would've done the trick for eligible nationalities, but US passport cards aren't valid for Serbia.

So you indeed have to travel via Macedonia (or Montenegro)

Comment: It is possible that I can do a clockwise circle from Sofia to Nis (Serbia) to Pristina (Kosovo) and then cut through Serbia to Sofia. The question is, can I cross the boarder on route R124?

Comment: What would happen if you travelled EU - Serbia - Kosovo - N. Macedonia - Serbia? Would the entry stamp from the first entry to Serbia cause problems at the second entry?

Comment: montenegro is not macedonia, and is on west side. so, if he wants to go to bulgaria, he should not go to montenegro

Comment: @HanMah Yes, Bulgaria-Serbia-Kosovo-Serbia-Bulgaria is perfectly fine

Comment: @CharlieHarding You mean the lack of a Serbian exit stamp? Currently no; the Kosovan exit stamp at the Macedonian border shows when you left the territory Serbia claims as theirs